# how can I send a XML to spec URL though php?

Tags: php, xml, curl

How can I send a  XML to spec URL?

Every time a form is sent I want to send a xml file to a url ... how do I do that?

NOTE: xml file to be sent is always the same so I do not need to create new xml file each time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

1. Load XML into $xmldata.
2. Create headers:

   ```
   $header[] = "Host: www.site.com"; 
   $header[] = "Content-type: text/xml"; 
   $header[] = "Content-length: ".strlen($xmldata) . "\r\n"; 
   $header[] = $xmldata;
   ```
3. Run CURL:

   ```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_url, "http://www.site.com/receiving_script.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
   curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_CUStoMREQUEST, 'POST');
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   ```

This is just a sample code, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="xmlfile" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($xml)" />
```

would do the trick. But if the XML is always the same, why not just put the file onto the server and read it there, rather than wasting bandwidth sending it each time?